# Firebase realtime database high download usage

Tags: facebook, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

We are using firebase realtime database to save scores for each level for users that are connected with facebook. We are still testing this feature and everything works fine, but the download usage is really really high. Every time that user opens the app, I download very small ammount of data, around 20 bytes, and aditional 5 bytes for every level that he starts. After few minutes the download usage started showing more than 100kB which is a lot and won't scale financially when we realease this to our users. Here is the data structure that we are using:

```
users{
  facebook_id{
    "firebase_id" : firebaseId,
    "max_level" : maxLevel,
    "stars" : numberOfStars,
    "scores" : {
      level : score,
    }
  }
}
```

I also did some CLI database profiling, and there was 0 Nonindexed Queries and the usage seemed correct. [image: Here] Here is the screenshot.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? If this is just SSL overhead(which still seems too big), there noting else we could do but setup our own server.

Comment: Maske, Did you find a solution to it.

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Comment: Having the same problem, insanely huge download usage for a very small database size with only few users.

Comment: Same here, I'm still developing, me alone, (no traffic, no users, no indexation). They are charging me for over-usage.

Comment: Can you post a sample response for your query here and also the code where you are querying. I have a doubt that either you are making more queries than needed or your database structure isn't optimal causing over fetch

Comment: @LukaMaške Can the overhead be the problem. I started a similar question about the overhead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680982/what-is-the-costs-in-bytes-for-the-overhead-of-a-request-in-realtime-database

Comment: Maybe you are using real-time listener callbacks instead of reading data once with GetValueAsync() function and maybe it causes this issue. You don't need to listen to callbacks like ValueChanged or ChildAdded right? If you already reading data once, it's a different problem of course. I didn't see your code.

Comment: Hording and centralizing data, is always a bad idea in a non-relational databases.. you need to divide in to more flat structures..

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 : Store the lengthy data in seperate locations

- If this is the data structure
- Everytime the user checked his maxlevel, the underlying scores for each level gets called.
- Avoid this by splitting the summated result in seperate path

#### Bad Way

```
users{
  facebook_id{
    "firebase_id" : firebaseId,
    "max_level" : maxLevel,
    "stars" : numberOfStars,
    "scores" : {
      level : score,
    }
  }
}
```

### Better way- Split into user details and user score details

#### User details

```
Contains only max level and number of stars
users{
  facebook_id{
    "firebase_id" : firebaseId,
    "max_level" : maxLevel,
    "stars" : numberOfStars
  }
}
```

#### User Score details

- Contains scores of levels in seperate path
- client side can check `users_scores/facebook_id/scores/<levelname>` exists? if exists, fetch score

```
users_scores{
  facebook_id{
    "scores" : {
      level1 : score1
    },
    {
      level2 : score2
    }
  }
}
```

- Calculate the total number of stars by using cloud functions
  OR
- NOT RECOMMENDED: calculate the total number of stars in the client section by reading the `stars` from `users` path, and not going through `users_scores`. Just update the path `users_scores/facebook_id/scores/<levelname>` from client itself

#### KEY POINT

- Rather than reading all stars in every fetch request
- Fetch the last updated stars, and update the new stars to it.
- Update the star in specific level by acessing only a single path
- Which will be empty for the first time and will contain value if he already completed the level.

Comment: nice logic.... after all it is nonrelational, and splitting always works... since most of the time you want need all the data at once but you work on chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues in my iOS app. A  250 kilobytes database was generating an incredible amount of traffic. I did a 1-hour CLI database profiling, which showed a total of 40 kilobytes of traffic, while the Usage tab in the Firebase console for the same hour showed 20 megabytes.

After a lot of tests it turned out that Firebase fetches data from the database after the reference initialization, even without any read or write operations.

Every time a user simply opened and closed the app, the Firebase console showed that around 8 kilobytes of data were downloaded from the database. To avoid this, before the initial reference to the database, you need to set `isPersistenceEnabled = false` however, note that this will also disable the offline mode for the Realtime Database.

```
import FirebaseDatabase

class RealtimeDatabase {
    
    static let shared = RealtimeDatabase()
    
    let database: Database
    let dbReference: DatabaseReference
    
    private init() {
        database = Database.database(url: "https://your-database-url.firebasedatabase.app")
        database.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        dbReference = database.reference()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you retrieving a lot more data from the JSON file than you intend to. Google have laid out some guidelines for how to structure your data best so that you only affect as little information as possible.

> Avoid using too many indexes. An excessive number of indexes can
>   increase write latency and **increases storage costs** for index entries.
>
> Be aware that indexing fields with monotonically increasing values,
>   such as timestamps, can lead to hotspots which impact latency for
>   applications with high read and write rates.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#indexes

Also this section underneath Indexes might be of help:

> Avoid writing to a document more than once per second. For more
>   information, see Updates to a single document.
>
> Use batch operations for your writes and deletes instead of single
>   operations. Batch operations are more efficient because they perform
>   multiple operations with the same overhead as a single operation.
>
> Use asynchronous calls where available instead of synchronous calls.
>   Asynchronous calls minimize latency impact. For example, consider an
>   application that needs the result of a document lookup and the results
>   of a query before rendering a response. If the lookup and the query do
>   not have a data dependency, there is no need to synchronously wait
>   until the lookup completes before initiating the query.
>
> Do not use offsets. Instead, use cursors. Using an offset only avoids
>   returning the skipped documents to your application, but these
>   documents are still retrieved internally. The skipped documents affect
>   the latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read
>   operations required to retrieve them.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#read_and_write_operations

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. But the question is asking for Firebase REALTIME database but your answer is Cloud FIRESTORE which totally different.